# User Acceptance Testing with Single sign on enabled

Tags: manual-testing

our client want to test the system, UAT. But they have a single sign-on implemented. They want 1 single person to log in as 4 different users on their machine to perform UAT? But I assume single sign-on won't allow 2 different logins on their machine. How do we handle this situation?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you reffering to PC running Windows operating system and using LDAP provider for SSO?

Comment: "They want 1 single person to log in as 4 different users on their machine"...this strikes me as an odd requirement. Is the actual goal to test concurrency--having multiple users signed in at once? In that case, there may be other approaches to consider than those that are limited by the one human on one machine approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could try different browsers not integrated with windows configuration. Try Firefox and its [derivatives](https://www.howtogeek.com/108608/6-alternative-browsers-based-on-mozilla-firefox/).

You could also create a virtual machine with bridged network adapter using built in Hyper-V if you use windows 10 and install there windows test machine without joining it to domain, so SSO will not force it to log in automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Try using incognito mode (chrome `ctrl+shift+n`).

Answer (score 1):

I realize that my answer is pretty late, but, I do have another solution that has worked well for me in the past.  When you start your browser, or other application, start it from file manager (option is not available in start menu).  Press shift + left click and select Run As Different user.  You can do this for each of the users (although I myself have gotten confused sometimes after having more than 2 or 3 different users running at the same time).

Answer (score 0):

Every software testing company do user acceptance testing before releasing any code to live environment.

For the scenario mentioned in question, user can use different browsers(Chrome, Firefox, IE, Safari) to logon with same credentials. Moreover, incognito mode also works for this scenario as it does not have the cache of the other logged-in session.

Apart from this, user can also sign-in using Sauce labs as it can allow user to create different nodes for multiple virtual machines.

Answer (score -1):

You can use different browsers:

- Chrome
- Safari
- Firefox
- Opera
  And course you can used Incognito mode for all these browsers too.

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything not already covered by existing answers.